# Filemaker 2013, Dynamically Altering a List

Tags: listview, foreach, filemaker

FM scripting noob here, got myself a copy of Filemaker and so far have found it quite interesting.

However I was wondering if its possible to limit whats displayed from a list when an incremental gets over a certain amount.

For example say I have a list of tasks, with minutes attached.

Ideally I would like to keep a running total of the minutes and when they reach more than say 450 (number of minutes in an average working day) it stops displaying any more records.

Basically so that I can have a quick look of roughly what tasks I am likely to get done today.

Or in other words is it possible to replicate the following PHP code within Filemaker

```
<?php

$foo=0; //running total of mins

foreach($tasks as $task){

$foo=$foo + $task['mins'];

if($foo > 450){break;}else{echo "Task: ".$task['name']."<br>";}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Basically so that I can have a quick look of roughly what tasks I am
>   likely to get done today.

In Filemaker, you *find* the records you want to display (or *omit* those that you do not).

However, finding on the basis of a summary is not possible. IMHO, the simplest solution to your problem is to show all tasks and conditionally format the group you are interested in. The formula for the conditional formatting would be =

```
Tasks::sRunTotal < 450
```

where `sRunTotal` is a Summary field, Total of Minutes (running). The remaining records would continue to be shown below, with no ill effect, in another color/font/what will you.

Or, if you prefer, you can have a script loop over the records until:

```
Tasks::sRunTotal > 450
```

then use the Omit Muliple Records[] script step to omit the remaining records.

Comment: This sounds like what I had in mind, so would I need to utilise a button that when pushed ran the script you mentioned?

Comment: Ahh I get what you mean, how do I create a summary field though?

Comment: Scratch that figured it out, just needed to tick the running total box on my existing summary field.

Answer (score 0):

You could Loop over your sorted list of tasks and add the primary keys for qualifying tasks to a return-separated global field. Exit the Loop when the hours are exceeded. Then use this global field as the source in a relationship pointing to tasks.

```
Set Variable [ $hours = 0 ]
Set Variable [ $MaxHours = 8 ]
Loop
    Exit Loop If ($hours > $maxHours)
    Set Field [ myTable::globalKeyField ; myTable::globalKeyField & "¶" & task::id ]
    Set Variable [ $hours = $hours + myTable::duration ]
    Go To Record/Request [ Next ]
End Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start by creating the running total in the task database. If you have a self-referenced TO sorted by your existing sort definition (whatever you are using for the initial stacked list), then create a calc field for TotalMinutes, defined as Min+sum(totalpriorrecords). I'm skimping on the guidance here for brevity, but totalpriorrecords would via TO relationship and the existing rank you are using.

You could do this then by creating a TO to the tasks, with a relationship to the table context of your layout, where your layout table has a calc or set field MinutesinaDay set to 450 and then REL is defined with task::minutes < context:MinutesinaDay.

In FM13, I think you could also do this much more easily with some sql query tricks against an existing TO and save the multiple TOs to grab what you need.

Once you have the limited task TO then you can create value list or portal that will only show the task list for items up to total sum of 450.